# After "git reset --hard" I am behind origin/master by 2 commits, how do I update origin/master?

Tags: git

I am working on a solo project and develop everything on master. I have made 2 commits and 2 pushes that I no longer want as my master branch. After running `git log` I find the id I need and run:

```
git reset --hard 36c75dccf125c1db6bc92f835cf1242010134f46
```

This is the state of the code I need as my current master branch.

After running `git commit -m "some-message"` I see

> your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded. (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

But I want this current state to be my main code on master branch. I do not want to `git pull`. What are the next steps?

Comment: The commit command is useless after the reset, you should have had a message warning about commiting without staged changes (and suggesting `--allow-empty-commit` which is not your solution). About your main question, short answer is to push with `--force`, **but** there's a ton of duplicates for this question. Searching for a good one (thank you @mkrieger1, excellent one).

Answer (score 1):

Just push your changes (removal of two commits) to upstream.

```
git push
```

or, if required:

```
git push --force
```

Comment: How could you ever not need force here?